# Detect fullscreen (F11 triggered) on Chrome

Tags: javascript

In Firefox 56.x , `window.fullscreen` says if the browser is in fullscreen state or not. How to detect the same in Chrome?

Note: Assume the fullscreen is triggered by `F11` || `Cmd + Shift + Enter` and not programmatically via any of `document` methods.

Answer (score 1):

A decent workaround might be to see if `screen.width === window.outerWidth && screen.height === window.outerHeight`.

Comment: What are the possible limitations in this workaround?